# Choice of Markov Random Field or Bayesian Network to model some causal and some non-causal links

Tags: causality, graphical-model, causal-diagram

Suppose you were modelling whether a person's ethnicity meant that they had different chances of getting a job due to discrimination. You have a couple of confounding variables e.g. deprivation - in England in 2019, [31% of Pakistanis lived in the most deprived 10% of neighbourhoods](https://www.ethnicity-facts-figures.service.gov.uk/uk-population-by-ethnicity/demographics/people-living-in-deprived-neighbourhoods/latest#overall-most-deprived-10-of-neighbourhoods-by-ethnicity), so they may not get the same education/work opportunities as some other groups.

Using $E$ for Ethnicity, $D$ for Deprivation, and $U$ for Unemployed, we could make a [Bayesian network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network) with edges
$$E \rightarrow D \rightarrow U,$$
but I wouldn't say that being Pakistani *caused* someone to grow up in a deprived area, it was just a correlation. (In the $E \rightarrow D \rightarrow U$ model we would also be testing if there was an additional $E \rightarrow U$ link that corresponded to discrimination.)

Perhaps a clearer example is age - in 2011 in England & Wales [49% of people with Mixed ethnicity were under 18, compared to 20% for White people](https://www.ethnicity-facts-figures.service.gov.uk/uk-population-by-ethnicity/demographics/age-groups/latest#age-profile-by-ethnicity). Being any particular ethnicity doesn't *cause* you to be a different age. And age is related to unemployment - [in Sep-Nov 2021 in the UK, 10% of 18-24 year olds were unemployed vs 3.1% of 25-49 year olds](https://www.ons.gov.uk/employmentandlabourmarket/peoplenotinwork/unemployment/datasets/unemploymentbyageanddurationseasonallyadjustedunem01sa).

In this situation is it preferable to use a DAG since I believe there are some causal links, e.g. young people have less work experience and education so it makes sense that they would find it harder to get jobs? But some of the variables are linked but not in a causal manner - I could just choose an arbitrary direction for the arrow in these situations? Would it be better to use a [Markov random field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_random_field) in this case? Or is there some hybrid model with both association and causal edges?

Comment: I'm not so sure that you need have no arrows between $E$ and $D.$ You could have a bidirectional arrow. It is not unreasonable to think that the first Pakistanis to go to England had to live in a more affordable place (hence $E\to D$), but that then the presence of Pakistanis in a particular neighborhood attracted more Pakistanis (hence $D\to E$).

Comment: @Adrian Keister Thanks, I thought a Bayesian network graph had to be acyclic - wouldn't the arrows in both directions introduce a cycle $E \rightarrow D \rightarrow E$?

Comment: Typically, yes. However, if you read Pearl, at least, you will see that he has a few ways you can deal with bidirectional arrows.